# wpf: separate mousedouble click on datagrid rows from headers

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

DataGrid has MouseDoubleClick event. Any double click(on header, empty space) on DataGrid calls this action. Need call this action only by double click on selected row. Any ideas?

Comment: Please share code that you have already tried and where you are getting stuck so we can better assist you.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 options:

1. Add and remove EventHandler for  Double click event in code behind, when user select any row.  (So, you hase to add and remove one EventHandler  in another EventHandler ) 
   As for me, it's bad solution.
2. Add 2 event handlers in DataGrid. In first you can get ROW and store it to some variable. In another you can get CELL and check that it IN selected ROW. If not, ignore it, by returning from handler. Add this logic in the start of method.

   ```
   if(selectedCellRow != selectedRow)
   { 
       return;
   }
   ```